# How to get another class based upon type of object?

Tags: python

I have a use case where I want to get another class based upon the **type of object**.

For one solution, I have created a **dict** where I am maintaining this relation and using type to match among classes.

For example, consider the below code

```py
class classA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A called"

class classB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B called"

MAP = {
   A: classA,
   B: classB
}

class C(object):
    pass

class A(C):
    pass

class B(C):
    pass

obj can be object of A or B.

new_cls = MAP.get(type(obj), 'None')
new_obj = new_cls()
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to reinvent [type-based polymorphic dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/125337/41316)...

I assume you don't have the hand on classes `A` and `B` (=> they belong to the stdlib or a third-part one that you don't want to fork), else the very obvious solution would be to simply implement `call` (or any other method) on those classes directly.

In this context, your solution is actually quite pythonic. The other possible pythonic solution would be [using `functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), and the last resort evil ugly but-sometimes-a-lifesaver  solution to [monkeypatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626250/41316) `A` and `B`.

Comment: can you check my edited question, does this holds true also if instead of methods, i require different class types to create an object

Comment: @DeepanshuArora python has a notion of "callable object" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable). Functions are callable, methods are callable, classes are callable (that's how you instanciate them), and you can define your own callables. My answer applies to all callable objects.

Answer (score 2):

why not to:

```
class C(object):
    pass

class A(C):
    def call:
        print("A")

class B(C):
    def call:
        print("B")
obj.call()
```

or use the inheritance.

**But wait** , what if i can't do this and really need to know which class is this??

> > you can use this `obj.__class__.__name__` this will work for old style and [new style Classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)

Comment: call is just an example, I may want to get some other class reference also

Comment: @DeepanshuArora you'll need to show a more elaborate example in your original question so that it can then be more completely answered.

Comment: @lurker edited the example. does it makes sense now?